# Unwanted white background visible around UITableView when rotating from landscape to portrait

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, uiview, rotation

I have a UITableView in an iPad application that I am working on. When I start in a portrait view and rotate to landscape, the view rotates and the rotation looks good.

However, when I rotate from landscape to portrait, there is a white edge that is displayed during the rotation. It appears as though the UITableView is resized to fit the portrait display at the beginning of the rotation. (When rotating TO landscape, resizing first means that no white will be seen.)

Through a few screenshots that I have been able to grab, it appears that the animation order is as follows:

1. Resize UITableView
2. Perform rotation animation
3. Resize UIToolbar

While researching this, I found some people suggesting to change the UIWindow's background color to match your view (blue in this case), but my real UITableView does not have a solid color background, so this method is not sufficient.

I would like to be able to control when the rotation of individual views occur so that I can prevent this white border from being visible during rotation. Or if there is a better approach, please share that too!

[Edit] Here's a rough screenshot showing the white border during rotation:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the background color of the window layer to [UIColor blackColor]

Comment: This has worked for me. Or if you have another view behind the table view, setting that background to black also.

Comment: Turns out more complicated for me. I'm using an image as the background for my cells (table views w/o images rotate correctly by default). Setting the background of the table's containing view to black still resulted in a white border. By setting my table view's background color to black I am able to do your suggestion. But now during rotation I can see that the UIToolbar resizes smoothly (never revealing the black) while the table view resizes immediately (showing black). So you see a wide toolbar and a skinny table view during the rotation. This is certainly improved! (but not quite ideal)

Comment: this worked for me too! In my appDelegate, i have the line:     self.window.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

Comment: You can also change it in the storyboard, by clicking on the main view, going to the Attributes Inspector, and changing the "Background" dropdown to "Black Color".  You can also use "Clear Color", which could have a similar effect